# How can I group 4 cell in a row in jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Here is my code:

```
    import { Col, Container, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useTrafficSnapShot } from "./useTrafficSnapShot";
export default function TrafficSnapShot() {
    let [error, isLoading,
        selectedSnapShotList,
        searchSnapShot] = useTrafficSnapShot();
    return (
        <div>
            {
                !isLoading &&
                <Container fluid>
                    <Row><Col>Traffic Snap Shot</Col></Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Col><input onChange={e => searchSnapShot(e.target.value)} required type="text" /></Col>
                    </Row>
                    {
                        selectedSnapShotList.map((snapShort, index) => {
                            let temp = [], obj;
                            obj = <Col><div>{snapShort.location}</div></Col>

                            if ((index % 4) === 0) {
                                temp.push(<Row>);
                            }
                            temp.push(obj);
                            if ((index % 3)===0 ){
                                temp.push(</Row>)
                            }
                            return temp;
                        })

                    }
                </Container>
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

I want to group 4 `Col` in a `Row`.
I got the following error message on `temp.push(</Row>)`.

```
Line 26:43:  Parsing error: Unexpected token (26:43)
```

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

JSX element converts to React.createElement

Doing like this: `temp.push(<Row>);` and this `temp.push(</Row>)` really makes no sence.

`<Row>test</Row>` converts into `React.createElement(Row, null, 'test')` and it returns an object

How you expect to separate that object in 2 halves ?!

Just move the Row outside of the .map method

```
  <Row> 
    {  selectedSnapShotList.map((snapShort, index) => {
           return <Col key={index}><div>{snapShort.location}</div></Col>
     })}
  </Row>
```